# How to use XQuery to simulate STRING_AGG() (grouped string concatenation)?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xquery

I have XML data which I need to convert to relational form. I use XQuery cause I don't know the number of address nodes. I'd like to get the whole address/adresses separeted by a comma. I guess I need to use LET clause but I'm still receiving an error.

Here's my code:

```sql
declare @xml as xml = '<root>
    <Row>
        <proceeding>
            <signatures>V GU 86/18</signatures>
            <signatures>V GUp 9/19</signatures>
            <signatures>V GUp 8/19</signatures>
        </proceeding>
        <entity>
            <info>
                <cleaned_name>Kate Smith</cleaned_name>
            </info>
            <address>
                <town>London </town>
                <house_number>1 </house_number>
                <flat_number>1</flat_number>
                <street>Downing Street</street>
                <zip_code>00-001</zip_code>
            </address>
        </entity>
        <entity>
            <info>
                <cleaned_name>John Smith</cleaned_name>
            </info>
            <address>
                <town>Washington </town>
                <house_number>1</house_number>
                <flat_number>1</flat_number>
                <street>Pennsylvania Avenue</street>
                <zip_code>00-001</zip_code>
            </address>
        </entity>
    </Row>
</root>'
```

```sql
select 
    isnull(STUFF(a.x.query('for $s in  entity/info/cleaned_name return <x>{concat(",",$s)}</x>').value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,''),'') as 'Nazwa podmiotu' 
   ,isnull(STUFF(a.x.query('for $s in proceeding/signatures return <x>{concat(",",$s)}</x>').value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,''),'') as 'Sygnatura'
   --,isnull(STUFF(a.x.query('for $s in entity let $L := $s/entity/address   return <x>{concat(",",Address="{$s/Address}")}</x>').value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,''),'') 
from @xml.nodes('/root/Row') as a(x)
```

My desired outcome[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
select 
 isnull(STUFF(a.x.query('for $s in  entity/info/cleaned_name return <x>{concat(",",$s)}</x>').value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,''),'') as 'Nazwa podmiotu' 
,isnull(STUFF(a.x.query('for $s in proceeding/signatures return <x>{concat(",",$s)}</x>').value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,''),'') as 'Sygnatura'
,isnull(STUFF(a.x.query('for $s in entity
                         return <x>
                                {
                                concat(", ",($s/address/zip_code/text())[1]," "
                                           ,($s/address/town/text())[1]," "
                                           ,($s/address/street/text())[1]," "
                                           ,($s/address/house_number/text())[1],"/"
                                           ,($s/address/flat_number/text())[1]
                                          )
                                }
                                </x>').value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,''),'') 
    from @xml.nodes('/root/Row') as a(x);
```

The result

```
Nazwa podmiotu          Sygnatura                           AllAdresses
Kate Smith,John Smith   V GU 86/18,V GUp 9/19,V GUp 8/19    00-001 London  Downing Street 1 /1, 00-001 Washington  Pennsylvania Avenue 1/1
```

### UPDATE Multiple addresses and identical data

You can try this (according to your comment)

Your test data with one second address and one copied address:

```
declare @xml as xml = '<root>
    <Row>
        <proceeding>
            <signatures>V GU 86/18</signatures>
            <signatures>V GUp 9/19</signatures>
            <signatures>V GUp 8/19</signatures>
        </proceeding>
        <entity>
            <info>
                <cleaned_name>Kate Smith</cleaned_name>
            </info>
            <address>
                <town>London </town>
                <house_number>1 </house_number>
                <flat_number>1</flat_number>
                <street>Downing Street</street>
                <zip_code>00-001</zip_code>
            </address>
            <address>
                <town>Yorkshire </town>
                <house_number>1 </house_number>
                <flat_number>1</flat_number>
                <street>Morning Street</street>
                <zip_code>00-999</zip_code>
            </address>
        </entity>
        <entity>
            <info>
                <cleaned_name>John Smith</cleaned_name>
            </info>
            <address>
                <town>Washington </town>
                <house_number>1</house_number>
                <flat_number>1</flat_number>
                <street>Pennsylvania Avenue</street>
                <zip_code>00-001</zip_code>
            </address>
            <address>
                <town>Washington </town>
                <house_number>1</house_number>
                <flat_number>1</flat_number>
                <street>Pennsylvania Avenue</street>
                <zip_code>00-001</zip_code>
            </address>
        </entity>
    </Row>
</root>'
```

--The query

```
select 
 isnull(STUFF(a.x.query('for $s in  entity/info/cleaned_name return <x>{concat(",",$s)}</x>').value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,''),'') as 'Nazwa podmiotu' 
,isnull(STUFF(a.x.query('for $s in proceeding/signatures return <x>{concat(",",$s)}</x>').value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,''),'') as 'Sygnatura'
,isnull(STUFF(a.x.query('for $s in entity/address
                            return
                            <x>{concat(", ",($s/zip_code/text())[1]," "
                                           ,($s/town/text())[1]," "
                                           ,($s/street/text())[1]," "
                                           ,($s/house_number/text())[1],"/"
                                           ,($s/flat_number/text())[1]
                                       )}</x>')
                   .query('for $a in distinct-values(/x/text()) return $a').value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,''),'') 
    from @xml.nodes('/root/Row') as a(x);
```

The idea in short:

We use the first XQuery to create a simple XML fragment like this

```
<x>, 00-001 London  Downing Street 1 /1</x>
<x>, 00-999 Yorkshire  Morning Street 1 /1</x>
<x>, 00-001 Washington  Pennsylvania Avenue 1/1</x>
<x>, 00-001 Washington  Pennsylvania Avenue 1/1</x>
```

With this we can use a second XQuery and place `distinct-values()` there.

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side.

Comment: @Shnugo that's exactly what I wanted to accomplish. You're reliable as always. Many thanks.

Comment: @Shnugo, I'm just wondering if I can use distinct-values with this synthax? When I use it  this way: distinct-values (entity) I get an error.

Comment: @Arkadiusz Can you have more than one address per entity? Do you expect identical addresses (in all fields) ?

Comment: @Shnugo, I can have more than one address per entity and they can be identical in all fields.

Comment: @Shnugo, it's a very clever approach. It goes without saying that it's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!